# Taskbar button is flashing after restore

Tags: c#, winforms

After restoring a window from systray icon, the main form gets the focus and everything looks OK but the button on taskbar is flashing (not every time). What can be the reason and how to ensure it is not flashing? Here is my restore function:

```
    void win_restore()
    {
        if (notifyIconMin.Visible) // there is option for normal minimize or systray
        {
            notifyIconMin.Visible = false;
            this.Visible = true;
        }
        WindowState = last_state; // last_state can be maximized or restored(normal)
        BringToFront();
        Activate();
        Focus();
        Application.DoEvents(); // for faster redraw
    }
```

I suppose the problem is in the order of BringToFront/Activate/Focus

Comment: Pretty sure that is an OS setting, not your specific code.  If the [Prevent application from stealing focus](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/6232.aspx#102) option has been turned on.

Comment: *First* make yourself visible, *then* set the NotifyIcon.Visible property.  Nothing else.  This ensures you won't lose the foreground, the kind of problem that makes the button flash.

Comment: I.e. only to swap the order of notifyIcon.Visible and this.Visible?